# Indentation error in Python Program

Tags: python, indentation

My code is -

```
def factorial(number):

result = 1

while number > 0:

result = result*number

number = number- 1

return result

in_variable = input("Enter a number to calculate the factorial of")

print factorial(in_variable)
```

I am getting an indentation error on line :

```
number = number- 1
```

My error is: `Unexpected indent`

Why is that?

Regards,

Nupur

Comment: Ironically, you stripped out all the indentation. Reproduce it accurately so that it can be investigated.

Comment: Can you post your code with the *actual formatting* you're using? As you're no doubt aware, in Python indentation matters. Don't forget that spaces and tabs cannot be mixed either.

Answer (score 2):

The code you've posted shows no indentation at all. Remember, for Python, [indentation matters](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html).

After indenting your code, you are still facing two bugs:

1. you are using `input`, which means you are using Python3 OR you should have been using `raw_input`. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4915361/2476444), which explains the difference very well. If you are using Python3, then it's not correct to use the `print` statement: you should be using the [`print` *function*](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function). If you're using Python2, you should be using `raw_input`.
2. Your function, `factorial`, expects a number, yet you are passing it a string (which is the return value of `raw_input` and `input`). Convert to int first.

This code is properly indented and works on Python3. Use `raw_input` rather than `input` if you're working with Python2.

```
def factorial(number):
    result = 1
    while number > 0:
        result = result*number
        number = number- 1
    return result

in_variable = input("Enter a number to calculate the factorial of")

print(factorial(int(in_variable)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def factorial(number):

    result = 1

    while number > 0:

       result = result * number

       number = number- 1

    return result
in_variable = int(input("Enter a number to calculate the factorial of"))

print(factorial(in_variable))
```

You need to convert the input from str to int.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure your indention str of int. You can easily check it with type(in_variable) and if it is str, you should change it to int with
in_variable = int(input("Enter a number to calculate the factorial of"))

```
def factorial(number):
result = 1
while number > 0:
    result = result*number
    number = number- 1
return result
```

in_variable = input("Enter a number to calculate the factorial of")